# W10 --> creating new folder on samba share creates 4 folders

Tags: windows, samba, directory

I using Ubuntu 16.10 Server and open an Samba Share.

Access on W10 works fine. But if I create a single Folder, 4 folders apear!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by adding *"Everyone"* *"All"* permissions.

[image: looks like this]

Comment: @Zanna it works for me (had same issue) machine is for testing on local intranet so "Everyone" is not a concern. Did not test other specific users/groups.